# How to store a random integers in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my first question and I am very new to programming.

I want my program to assign a random value to three stats so that I can retrieve the stats later for calculations. Here's the code I have so far:

```
import random
stats = {'strength' : 0, 'dexterity' : 0, 'intelligence' : 0}

for value in stats:
    value = random.randint(1,18)
    print (value)

for key, value in stats.items():
    print (key, value)
```

The output comes up like  this:

```
5
1
9
intelligence 0
strength 0
dexterity 0
```

Why does it keep resetting the values to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first for loop the `value` is a copy of the data not a reference to it.

```
import random
stats = {'strength' : 0, 'dexterity' : 0, 'intelligence' : 0}

for key, value in stats.items():
    value = random.randint(1,18)
    stats[key] = value # assign the value to dictionary
    print (value)

for key, value in stats.items():
    print (key, value)
```

Another problem with your code is that in the same loop you are iterating over the key and not the value (as your code seems to indicate)

```
for value in stats: # this is the key ['strength', 'dexterity', 'intelligence']
    value = random.randint(1,18)
    print (value)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to work, I'm just trying to understand why it works. The part I have trouble understanding is the `for stat in stats:` section. It seems to me that `stat` can be replaced with anything. I could write `for spam in stats:` and it would work just as well. I don't understand what the significance of that name is.

Comment: You're right you could replace stat with whatever you like. 'stat' is just a variable and is defined the first time the for loop is run and has a scope, where it works in the code, that is limited to the for loop. Each iteration of the loop changes stat's value

Answer (score 0):

> > > Why does it keep resetting the values to zero?

It doesn't. You've never set the values in the dictionary.

Try this:

```
for value in stats:
    stats[value] = random.randint(1,18)
    print (value, stats[value])
```

Answer (score 0):

You never changed the values stored in stats.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the random value to the `stats` dictionary, just printing them out.

I think this is what you want

```
import random
stats = {'strength' : 0, 'dexterity' : 0, 'intelligence' : 0}

for stat in stats:
    value = random.randint(1,18)
    stats[stat] = value
    print stats[stat]

for key, value in stats.items():
    print (key, value)
```